# why GAE backend start again & again?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am working on GAE+SpringMVC ,In my Project i wrote One backend but it's run more than 5 times but i want to run that backend only once.Please check my code below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gDirectory/testBackend.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testBackend(HttpServletRequest reg)
    {

         final  Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
         logger.warning("calling updateOrgChart.htm.....");

        try {
            String url="/gDirectory/testbackend1.htm";
            Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
            TaskOptions objTskOptions=  TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl(url)
                //  .countdownMillis(countmilliseconds)
                    .header("Host", BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("testbackend"))
                    .method(Method.GET);
                     queue.add(objTskOptions);

        } catch(Exception e){
        ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getName(), e);
        logger.warning("Exception in adding oldcustomer..161."+e);
        logger.warning("Exception in adding oldcustomer..161."+e.getMessage());
        logger.warning("Exception in adding oldcustomer..161."+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
        return "testBackend";
    }
```

**Mybackend**

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/gDirectory/testbackend1.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testBackend1(HttpServletRequest reg)
    {

         final  Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
         logger.warning("calling updateOrgChart.htm.....");

        try {
             logger.warning("This is my testbackend...........................");
             LifecycleManager.getInstance().setShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook() {
                  public void shutdown() {
                    LifecycleManager.getInstance().interruptAllRequests();
                  }
                });
        } catch(Exception e){
        ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getName(), e);
        logger.warning("Exception in adding oldcustomer..161."+e);
        logger.warning("Exception in adding oldcustomer..161."+e.getMessage());
        logger.warning("Exception in adding oldcustomer..161."+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
        return "testBackend";
    }
```

**backend.xml**

```
    <backend name="testbackend">
        <class>B2</class>
        <instances>5</instances>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>
```

this backend run more than 7 times ...but i want to run only one time any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your Backend task threw an exception (perhaps check the logs in the App Engine console), in which case the Push Queue will retry (with exponential back-off).  If this is the case, the console will show you the last response status and the number of retries.